# AspNet Membership - Centralizing Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

Right now we have several databases, each individual database has its own aspnet membership tables. We want to centralize all the membership to one database. For instance a main login page where they will specify the database, username and password. Then we would check on the centralized database and authenticate and redirect them to their account based on the database name they inputed on the textbox.

What is the best way to do this?, there maybe multiple usernames that are the same in different databases and this is my challenge.

Comment: Can you post the table structure and some sample data, with duplicates, of the membership table?

Comment: if the user name and pass word are consistent across the multiple databases, then when you import the data into a Centralized Single Database this should not be a problem. you would need to create a Script or Stored Procedure that would do the Bulk Insert based on Selecting Distinct records where !Exist in your Target Database if I am understanding your question correctly `Linked Servers may be the route to go`

Comment: We use the aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Users and aspnet_Roles. So in database A maybe a jhon and in database B there maybe a john also in the aspnet_Users table. Both are different people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net Membership has **Applications table**. As long as you have different application name for different website, you can merge them into one big database; chances of duplicating user id (which is stored as uniqueid) is very low.

When user logins, you need the following 3 fields -

1. Application (this can be DropDownLis)
2. Username
3. Password

### Create Own Validation

You cannot use custom Membership Provider to validate user which only accept username and password.

```
// ValidateUser method doesn't take any additional parameter
public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
```

So you need to implement own validation method to validate user from Merged Database.

### Note

If you are redirecting to different website, please take a note of Form Authentication's limitation. For example, it cannot transfer authentication cookie from www.one.com to www.two.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to assume that "user123" in database1 and "user123" in database2 are the same individual?

If so, you can just merge as DJ KRAZE suggested.  If not, you'll have to create new users for the duplicated user names.   You could write a fairly simple SQL script to do this by appending a number to the end of the ID.

Like.... found "john" in database 1, create "john1" user.  As I recall, the aspnet_membership database comes with a pretty robust set of stored procedures for creating users and so forth that create all the proper table entries.  I would definitely use those, rather than trying to freestyle insert/update statements, if you end up going that route

Comment: yep they are different people, john in db 1 is not the same john in db2

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can select the database to connect to on your logincontrol. so create a dropdown where users can select the database to connect to and then use that selection as your database. have a look at number 4 on http://forums.asp.net/t/1403132.aspx/1
the selection can be the connectionstring name that specifies the database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the best thing you can do is prefix the usernames based on the source database on duplicates and delegate the consolidation to the end-user.